# Chained Fetch Promises (JSON, React, Webpack, NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I need to fetch something 10 times and return the JSON of each request and push that into state.
Most of the fetching works, but slows down about half way and halts before it completes.
The promises seem to accept the 'cors' response, not the actual json, and thus triggers prematurely.

Also, I don't like how I have to repeat the same code so many times just to change the offset, but I spent hours fiddling with a for loop and I got stuck, so if you guys can suggest a better way to do this that would be awesome.

Here's the code:

```
function FetchAll(API_KEY, CX, query, E, that, pushState){

    fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=${E.target.value}&key=${API_KEY}`, {
      method: 'get',
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json()
    }).then(function(uploads){
        console.log(uploads)
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=${uploads.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads}&key=${API_KEY}&part=snippet&maxResults=50`)
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json()
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
      that.setState({yt:data})
    }).then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${1}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${11}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${21}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${31}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${41}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${51}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${61}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${71}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${81}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${91}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))
    .then(function(){
      return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=10&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${101}`)
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(r => pushState(r))

}

export default FetchAll
```

In case you were wonering, FetchAll is being called in the main App.js file, with everything being sent to it in parameters.

This is pushState (if needed)

```
FetchAll(API_KEY, CX, query, e, that,
    (r) => {
      console.log(r)
      let c = that.state.compareRaw
      c.push(r)
      that.setState({
        compareRaw: c
      })
    }
    )
}
```

> 'that' is a reference to *'this'*

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try using async/await, since you tagged reactjs, if you are using redux, I would suggest using `redux-saga` a better way to handle side effects ?

Comment: Could you be more precise with the symptoms you're observing? What part of "the fetching" does not work? What differences do you observe between instances that work and those that don't? What does "slows down about half way" mean? Where is half way? How is it halting before completing? Is an error thrown? Are requests not receiving responses? If you've figured out that you're incorrectly expecting certain data to be json when it's actually something else, what's currently keeping you from resolving that issue?

Comment: As mentioned above, async/await is good here for describing dependency relations. But for requests and work that do not depend on each other, an array (along with a map/forEach/loop) and a `Promise.all()` will make your code much nicer.

Comment: Maybe you should think about ```async```.  I think ```asynk.eachSeries``` would be fine in here. You can also try if ```parallel``` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decide which request are waterfall request and which requests are parallel requests.

In waterfall model current request is dependent from previous request result, and is handled with sequencing `.then()` functions

In parallel model request are independent and can all fire in the same time. It can be solved with `bluebird` as a great helper tool for promises.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.all([fetch(...), fetch(...)...., fetchN(...)], 
            (result1, result2, result3 ..., resultN) => {
              //handle results
            })
```

You can always wrap api call in a function:

```
function search(start, limit) {
    return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${API_KEY}&num=${limit}&cx=${CX}&q=${query}&start=${start}`)  
}
```

All together now

```
fetch(...) // request 1
.then((response) => fetch(...)) // request 2
.then((response) => {
   const apiCalls = [];
   for let i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
      apiCalls.push( search(i*10+1, 10) );
   }
   return Promise.all(apiCalls);
})
.then((...results) => {
   // handle search results
})
```

Hope it helps.